# How to setup Webhook with github for every PR needs to trigger Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I want to run a Jenkins job on every PR.

Scenario: I am using enterprise Github, everyone has there own forked repo. Whenever someone opens PR against main(monitor) repo I want to run Jenkins job for that PR itself.

Comment: Github has a manual on setting up Webhooks. Did you follow it? Have you encountered any issues?

Comment: I am using the "pull_request" event of Github webhook whenever I open, edit, close any PR it sends Payload to Jenkins but Jenkins is not triggering the job. Jenkins is only triggering whenever PR got merge to the master(default) branch. It looks like Jenkins is only behaving for the default branch
in Jenkins, I am using the "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" plugin.

Comment: You need to follow multiple branches, it's best done with either Multibranch plugin or Github Organization plugin. You can filter the regular branches to not trigger jobs so only PRs will trigger.

Comment: Thanks, @MaratC, I have used the "GitHub Branch Source" plugin to achieve this scenario. It is working as expected